# Custom class validation not working?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am currently developing a web project with ASP.NET MVC. I have a create page in it, and it creates an entity that corresponds to a database table through SQL server. I needed some validation that was better than just simply the 'required' tag, so I opted to use a custom validation class. I coded the class exactly like my other custom validation classes that work perfectly, yet for some reason this class is not firing upon page submit no matter what I try.

Viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
     //my other properties         

      [ValidateCreateDate(ErrorMessage = "Date must be after or on today's date.")]
      public DateTime? RequestedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Class:

```
public class ValidateCreateDateAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private context db = new context();

    public override bool IsValid(object value) //breakpoint is never hit here
    {
      //code to check if it is valid or not
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model context.MyViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Data", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-2">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </div>
  }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#RequestedDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in config, included js-file for unobtrusive?

Comment: Yes, both of those are enabled and I did have the unobtrusive file attached in my actual code, thanks though @Mackan

Comment: @EliHellmer Is your form being submitted properly ? Is it hitting the "Create" action method ? Your code looks fine though

Comment: Yeah, I believe my action method code is fine because I have 2 other custom validation classes running of it that both work fine. Really weird

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code and it worked for me.

Comment: You are trying to check the validity of a date's range but inheriting from the RequiredAttribute class. There are various Attribute classes. You can even just override the base ValidationAttribute class.

Comment: did you use `ModelState.IsValid` in your action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as a comment recommends

> ModelState.IsValid

and return a error as here is explain how: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Validation implementation deriving **ValidationAttribute** not **RequiredAttribute**:

```
 namespace YourProject.Common.DataAnnotations
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
        public sealed class ValidateCreateDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Date is requierd, value most be after or on today's date.";
            public ValidateCreateDateAttribute()
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
                {
                    ErrorMessage = _defaultErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    Type type = value.GetType();
                    if (type.IsPrimitive && (type == typeof(DateTime) || type == typeof(DateTime?)))
                    {
                        var checkDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
                        //in UTC, if you are using timezones, use user context timezone
                        var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
                        //compare datetimes
                        if (DateTime.Compare(checkDate, today) < 0)
                        {
                            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                        }
                        //success
                        return ValidationResult.Success;
                    }
return new ValidationResult("Cannot validate a non datetime value");
                }
                //if value cannot be null, you are using nullable date time witch is a paradox
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! @SilentTremor